# How to add a new language in Sitecore 8?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm working on Sitecore 8 and want to add a new language but Im having a message:

> The spell checker dictionary does not exist.

[image: Sitecore - the spell dictionary does not exist]

Could you please help me?

Comment: it can be leave this input if haven't checking file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the dictionary files are stored in `sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Dictionaries\` directory.

There is no `en-AU` dictionary there by default (there are `en-UK` and `en-US` dictionaries). You can use one of them I guess. Or you can try google `en-AU` and use something from the Internet ["en-AU.tdf" google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22en-au.tdf%22).

Comment: Thanks Marek, I see !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by editing the "InvalidItemNameChars" setting temporarily.

Our project had a patch for InvalidItemNameChars like this:

This setting is usually in web.config. If you don't find it there, check "/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx" for InvalidItemNameChars.

I had to remove the '-' from the value and create the language. You will not get the error on not selecting the spell checker. You can leave it empty.

Once you are done creating the language add the '-' back to the config (in my case it was a patch config).